# Use a pointer when you have it's name in a string

Tags: delphi, pointers, devexpress, delphi-xe2

I have multiple pointers and each of their name is built like this `'str'+'name'`. So let's say that pointer 1's name will be `strpointer1`, pointer 2's name `strpointer2` and so on;

I have all those names stored somewhere and in a certain moment I will  have the pointer 1's name in a string variable and I will need to do something with that pointer at that point.

How do I use that pointer when all I have is his name in a string ?

***Better explanation( I hope):***

I a trying to use a localizer component of devexpress suite for translating a dinamically generated menu from a sql table;

For an example: for the caption of the 'File' component of a menu you declare in the localizer the translations for other languages and you will get a pointer (named by me 'filecap') to those translations.

When I am drawing the menu in the design time i would assign File.caption like this:

```
File.caption := cxgetresourcestring(@filecap);
```

**function cxgetresourcestring(apointer):string;**

but i am drawing the menu dinamically : I am reading my menu items from a TTable and after that i am storing them in a dynamic array. So this is the moment I was talking about, and normally i will do it like this:

```
MenuItems_Array[i].caption := tbl_menu.fieldbyname('MenuItemName').asstring;
```

but now i i want to use the localizer i tried this:

```
MenuItems_Array[i].caption := cxgetresourcestring(tbl_menu.fieldbyname('MenuItemName').asstring);
```

which returns an error of course: that pointer type and string don't match;

Comment: AFAIK, you use the map file to map the name of your variable *(pointer)* to an actual adress but that's not a solution one should use for a production environment.

Comment: At the moment your question is too vague for us to even begin answering it (unless @Lieven guessed right). Please show us, in pseudo-code if not real code, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Though I do not really understand your task: have you thought about using a TStringList? Here you can store the Names (strings) AND the Pointer into the Objects of the StrinList. (AddObject...)

Comment: For storing the multilingual object captions the TcxLocalizer uses it's own mecanism to store them in res files; and i can only get a caption by this funct cxgetresourcestring();

Comment: I don't know `cxGetResourceString` function at all, but something tells me, it needs to have a control's object instance as an input parameter and according to the control's name and type it finds the translation text and update the control, but you're trying to pass there a string, what drives that function crazy. But if I'm wrong and this function can take also a pointer to the string as an input, then try to use something like `cxGetResourceString(PChar(TableField.AsString))`.

Comment: @TLama -- already tried that but i get an error: [DCC Error] E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'cxGetResourceString'

Comment: Did you trying asking your question on the DevEx support forums?

Comment: @Jan Doggen --- yes but they are answering really hard and I am having a hard time with this issue, and in delphi language I can't find an Evaluate function;

Comment: There is Evaluate function in ToolsAPI unit, but I'm not sure that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you all for posting. I have found a solution for my problem: you need to call the cxgetresourcestring function and it parameter should be the original string value declared in dev express localizer for a certain object. I am not sure that this very clear for you, but i think that someone who will bump in the same problem will understand. thank you guys again for your support;

Comment: @CristianVasuica, thanks a lot for the solution. I had been trying for some hours already to solve exactly the same problem you had. :-) I think you should add it as an answer with a picture showing the `VCL Localizer Editor` and the `original value`. I'd certainly upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

The `cxGetResourceString` (and `cxSetResourceString`) function is designed to get (and set) the translation of the ready made DevExpress components.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's only designed to operate on resourcestring variables:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Resource_Strings

I think that this is not what you want at all. You want something like `gettext()` in C which DevExpress does not provide.

A list of some solutions:

http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatplocalize.htm

Also the Delphi IDE has built-in support for translation:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Localizing_Applications_by_Using_Translation_Manager_Index

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to enumerate a unit's resourcestrings. If it can, the solution would be a lot easier.

What you want to do can still be done if you are willing to maintain a register of all your string resources. It will need to be done manually though.

I would expect the following approach to work

```
var
  slResources : TStringList;
procedure RegisterResString(ResId : String; Address : Pointer);
begin
  slResources.AddObject(ResId, TObject(Address));
end;

function GetResourceAddress(ResId : string) : Pointer;
var idx : Integer;
begin
  if slREsources.Find(ResId, idx) then 
    Result := slResources.Objects[idx]
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Then you would need to register your string resource.

```
resourcestring
  Filecap = 'File';

procedure RegisterUnitRes;
begin
  RegisterResString('Filecap', @Filecap);
end;
```

And then you could call :

```
MenuItems_Array[i].caption := cxgetresourcestring(GetResourceAddress(tbl_menu.fieldbyname('MenuItemName').asstring));
```

There might be easier way to achieve this though.

Comment: Delphi's internationalization support will automatically extract all resourcestrings and properly set them up for translation, and then at runtime you just assign the resourcestring to the control's `Caption` or `Text` property, so you don't have to do all this work yourself.